# Allocating more memory to Talend Studio

Tags: java, jvm, talend, jvm-arguments

I am confused about the TOS_DI-win32-x86.ini settings.

Can you please help me to understand the meaning of following parameters given in the INI file:

```
-Xms1536m
-Xmx1536m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Comment: Please have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvms

Comment: 1) Set the initialheap size to 1536 Mb.  2) Set the max heap size to 1536Mb. 3) Set the max permgen heap size to 512Mb.  For more info, read the `java` manual entry, and google "java permgen"

Answer (score 0):

This means when you launch the 32bit version of the Talend Open Studio that you will start your java virtual machine with 1536mbs and then while the studio is running it can use up to 1536mbs of RAM and as long as you are on JDK 6 or 7 blocks of 512 mbs of memory will garbage collected at a time. Not that on JDK 1.8 MaxPermSize is no longer used.